# How to change the value of static var?

Tags: swift, enums, static, uicolor, collectionview

To control all the colors in my app, i create an enum containing static colors variable.

```
enum Color {
static var mainColor = UIColor(named: "mainColor")
static let red = UIColor(named: "red")
static let blue = UIColor(named: "blue")
static let green = UIColor(named: "green")
static let magenta = UIColor(named: "magenta")
static let indigo = UIColor(named: "indigo")
static let orange = UIColor(named: "orange")
static let pink = UIColor(named: "pink")
static let purple = UIColor(named: "purple")
static let yellow = UIColor(named: "yellow")

static let white = UIColor(named: "white")
```

}

I use mainColor for the background everywhere in my app. But In my SettingsView, there is a collection of this colors and when you tap one of them, I want to change the mainColor to it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == settingsView.primary.collection{
        let color = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor
        Color.mainColor = color
        
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It's not working? Is it because `color` is `Optional`?

Comment: @Larme When selecting the color, nothing changes.

Comment: What do you mean nothing change? It `Color.mainColor = color` called? Are you expecting to see a change of color? because to see it, you need to reload/refresh ALL the UI components.

Comment: To manage UI colors look at `UIAppearance` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

Comment: @Larme Yeah I do need to see the changes, so how can i refresh all the ui components